# Homestead nginx serve content from symlink generated via gulpfile and vinyl-fs

Tags: symfony, nginx, gulp, symlink

For my symfony project I manage my frontend assets using the following `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var vfs = require('vinyl-fs');

/**
* Location where to store the 3rd party libraries
*/
var frontend_folder="./frontend"
var vendor_folder=`${frontend_folder}/vendor`
var frontent_dev_folder_js=`${frontend_folder}/js`
var frontent_dev_folder_js=`${frontend_folder}/css`

/*################################### Installing Dependencies ###############################*/

//Move Bootstrap
gulp.task('move_bootstrap',function(done){

  var bootstrap_dir='./node_modules/bootstrap/dist';
  var dest=`${vendor_folder}/bootstrap`;

  var css_files=[`${bootstrap_dir}/css/bootstrap.min.css`,`${bootstrap_dir}/css/bootstrap.min.css.map`];
  var js_files=[`${bootstrap_dir}/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js`,`${bootstrap_dir}/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map`];

  gulp.src(css_files).pipe(gulp.dest(`${dest}/css`));
  gulp.src(js_files).pipe(gulp.dest(`${dest}/js`));

  done();
})

//Jquery & miscellanous Javascript move
gulp.task('move_jquery',function(done){
  var jqueryFiles=['./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'];
  gulp.src(jqueryFiles).pipe(gulp.dest(vendor_folder));

  done();
});

//For fontawesome
gulp.task('move_fontawesome',function(done){
  var path='./node_modules/font-awesome';
  var dest=vendor_folder+'/font-awesome';

  gulp.src(path+'/fonts/*').pipe(gulp.dest(dest+'/fonts'));
  gulp.src(path+'/css/font-awesome.min.css').pipe(gulp.dest(dest+'/css'));
  done();
});


/******* Build Final Steps ****************************************************/

gulp.task('link_assets',function(done){

  vfs.src(frontend_folder+'/*', {followSymlinks: false})
        .pipe(vfs.symlink('./web/assets/'));

  return done();
});

/* ############################################ Installing Dependencies ##################################### */

gulp.task('move_frontend', gulp.series(['move_bootstrap','move_jquery','move_fontawesome'],(done)=>{done()}));
gulp.task('dev',gulp.series(['move_frontend','link_assets'],(done)=>{done();}));

gulp.task('default',gulp.series(['dev'],(done)=>{done()}));
```

There is a task that generates a symlinks  fro any content that exists in a folder, located in my **project root** named `frontend` into a folder into the `./web/assets`. In other words my project root is:

```
-
-- frontend
...
-- web
---assets
---- ^any folder located in frontedn symlinked here^
```

Furthermore I place the following configuration for assets in `config.yml`:

```
framework:
...
    assets:
        packages:
            vendor:
                base_path: '/assets/vendor'
```

And I try to make my nginx to serve the symlinked content (used for development purpoces) for now I tried to place the following settings (based on [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks) ):

```
location ~ \/web\/assets {
    disable_symlinks off;
    root /home/vagrant/code/web/assets;
}
```

But when I visit an asset for example http://192.168.10.10/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css I get error 404. For development I use the the homestead vagrant image and i run the gulp tasks outside the vagrant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For development I use the the homestead vagrant image and i run the gulp tasks outside the vagrant.

That is the problem! 
The symlinks **outside** of vagrant are being mapped using full paths, in other words your symlink is pointing to a non-existed folder so the nginx when follows the symlink visits a non-existent file and as expected serves no content.

So I would suggest visiting via ssh the running vm:

```
vagrant ssh
```

Then go to folder `~/code`

```
cd ~/code
```

Remove the symlink

```
rm -rf ./web/assets/*
```

And rerun the gulp tasks

```
gulp
```

That will fix any problem you may have.